# How to parse a "/" separated string in XSLT / XPath?

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

The problem is as follows:  My XML has element with content "x/y". This indicates the running number of "part" coming in.  E.g. in first XML this element will have value 1/5, in second 2/5 and in last one 5/5. You get the point.  The element itself looks like

```
<part>x/y</part>
```

where x might be something between 1 and y, and y can be any number

I would need to find answer to two cases:

1. the result should be "Add" when x=1
2. the result should be "Complete", when x=y

How to solve this using XSL (version 1.0) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`substring-before()`](https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116/#function-substring-before):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="text"/>

  <xsl:template match="part">
    <xsl:variable name="x" select="substring-before(., '/')"/>
    <xsl:variable name="y" select="substring-after(., '/')"/>
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="$x = 1">Add</xsl:when>
      <xsl:when test="$x = $y">Complete</xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>
        <xsl:value-of select="concat('Unexpected values for x,y: ', $x, ',', $y)"/>
      </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thanks.  I added variable y similar way (with subsrting-after) and compared $x to $y for Complete. That did the trick.

Comment: @VpSoini: Oh, sorry, after re-reading your question, I see that I missed the $x=$y case.  Updated now (although it sounds like you've already covered it).  Thanks.